# The XML element 'tr' from namespace '' is already present in the current scope

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, .net-core

I'm trying to build a CDA document by serializing my object to XML, here's the XML part that causing me some troubles :

```
<component>
    <section>
        <templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.11'/>
        <templateId root='1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.3.6'/>
        <!--<id root='' extension=''/>-->
        <code code="11450-4" displayName="PROBLEM LIST" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC"/>
        <title>Active Problem - Problem List</title>
        <text>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Problem</th>
                        <th>Code</th>
                        <th>Code System</th>
                        <th>Start Date</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Asthma</td>
                        <td>195967001</td>
                        <td>SNOMED CT</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Active</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Costal chondritis</td>
                        <td>64109004</td>
                        <td>SNOMED CT</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Active</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>No impairment</td>
                        <td>66557003</td>
                        <td>SNOMED CT</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Active</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </text>
    </section>
</component>
```

And here are my C# classes for serializing it :

```
public class Section
{
    [XmlElement("templateId")]
    public List<IdElement> TemplateIds { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("code")]
    public CodeElement Code { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("text")]
    public Text Text { get; set; }
}
public class Text
{
    [XmlElement("table")]
    public Table.Table Table { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("list")]
    [XmlArrayItem("item")]
    public List<string> List { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("paragraph")]
    public List<string> Paragraphs { get; set; }
}
public class Table
{
    [XmlElement("thead")]
    public TRow Header { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("tbody")]
    public TRow Body { get; set; }
}
public class TRow
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "tr", Namespace = "")]
    [XmlArrayItem("td")]
    public List<string> RowData { get; set; }

    [XmlArray(ElementName = "tr", Namespace = "")]
    [XmlArrayItem("th")]
    public List<string> HeaderData { get; set; }
}
```

But when I try to serialize my CDA object now, it says that the type **tr** is already present in the Namespace, so I guess that this kind of XML table already exists, but I can't find a way to do it properly. 
Is there any solution to get around this problem ?

Here's the error log (without the stack trace) :

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type
>   'Project.Cda.Core.ClinicalDocument'. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting
>   property 'Component'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was
>   an error reflecting type 'Project.Cda.Core.Components.BaseComponent'.
>   ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting property 'Components'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There
>   was an error reflecting type 'Project.Cda.Core.Components.Component'.
>   ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting property 'Section'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was
>   an error reflecting type 'Project.Cda.Core.Components.Section'. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting
>   property 'Text'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an
>   error reflecting type 'Project.Cda.Core.Components.Text'. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting
>   property 'Table'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an
>   error reflecting type 'Project.Cda.Core.Components.Table.Table'. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting
>   property 'Header'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an
>   error reflecting type 'Project.Cda.Core.Components.Table.TRow'. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting
>   property 'HeaderData'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The XML
>   element 'tr' from namespace '' is already present in the current
>   scope. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for
>   the element.

Comment: In `TRow` You have `[XmlArray(ElementName = "tr", Namespace = "")]` on both `RowData` and `HeaderData`.  That can't work.

Comment: @dbc Hmm, thank you, I'll try something else. 
Is my only option to create seperate classes for Header and Body data ?

Comment: That's by far the easiest.  Other options include 1) Use [`[XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlchoiceidentifierattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to set up an `enum` array indicating whether a `<tr>` child element is a `<td>` or `<th>`.  2) Implement [`IXmlSerializable`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly).  (Don't do it!)  3) Do some trick with nested serializations inside an `[XmlAnyElement]` property as shown e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33180709/3744182).

Comment: Alright thanks, would have been cleaner to do it with the same element name but it works, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because, in `TRow`, You have

```
[XmlArray(ElementName = "tr", Namespace = "")]
```

on both `RowData` and `HeaderData`.  That can't work -- you are trying to specify the same element name for two different properties, and so get the error that you see, namely that *The XML element 'tr' from namespace '' is already present in the current scope.*

Furthermore, there's an additional problem with your models.  The `<tr>` elements inside `<tbody>` repeat, but your data model only allows for one `<tr>` element per body.

The following fixes both problems by introducing an intermediate `TablePart` to represent either the header and body portions of the table:

```
public class Table
{
    [XmlElement("thead")]
    public TablePart Header { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("tbody")]
    public TablePart Body { get; set; }
}

public class TablePart
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "tr", Namespace = "")]
    public List<TableRow> RowData { get; set; }
}

public class TableRow
{
    [XmlElement("td")]
    public List<string> Data { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("th")]
    public List<string> Headers { get; set; }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JIV6jR).