# XMLserializer, Entity Framework : Cannot serialize member of type ICollection see inner exception for more details

Tags: asp.net, xml, entity-framework, xml-serialization, icollection

I want to map XML elements into my database table (using Entity Framework):

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Participant), new XmlRootAttribute("participant"));
var participant = (Participant)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(content));
```

I have Participant table which I can access by

```
[XmlRoot("participant", Namespace = "")]
    public partial class Participant
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage",     "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Participant()
        {
            this.GroupParticipant = new HashSet<GroupParticipant>();
            this.ParticipantAddress = new HashSet<ParticipantAddress>();
            this.ParticipantPublisher = new HashSet<ParticipantPublisher>();
            this.ParticipantJob = new HashSet<ParticipantJob>();
            this.ParticipantProvider = new HashSet<ParticipantProvider>();
        }
        [XmlElement("firstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("lastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        //[XmlElement("address")]
        //[XmlElement("address")]
        //[XmlArray("HashSet<ParticipantAddress>"), XmlElement("address")]
        //[XmlArrayItem("ICollection<ParticipantAddress>")]
        //[XmlAttribute(DataType = "ICollection<ParticipantAddress>",  AttributeName = "address")]

[XmlElement("address", typeof(List<ParticipantAddress>))]
        public virtual ICollection<ParticipantAddress> ParticipantAddress { get; set; }
}
```

ParticipantAddress is ICollection:

```
[Serializable]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(HashSet<ParticipantAddress>))]
    public partial class ParticipantAddress
    {
        public int ParticipantAddressId { get; set; }
        public int ParticipantId { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("city")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("state")]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("zipCode")]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        public virtual Participant Participant { get; set; }
    }
```

Exception says:

> {"There was an error reflecting type 'x.Participant'."}

My inner Exception says:

> {"Cannot serialize member 'xParticipant.ParticipantAddress' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[x.ParticipantAddress, APS.Data.BatchInterface, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]', see inner exception for more details."}

I am reading XML by streamReader.

I have tried

- [XMLArray]
- Changing ICollection to List
- make class serializable

Is there any other way to overcome this problem or any examples related to my question or any changes I need to implement in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ICollection is not serializable.
- You can use DTO.
- You can change the collection type (i.e. with List<>) and with XML serialization attributes avoid circular references and/or disable lazy load (i.e. use eagerly load using Include method) or the risk is that you serialize the whole database.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have created a region and change the collection type ICollection<> to List<> because ICollection is an interface and interfaces are not serializable. But List<> is a class and this class implements all the below interfaces:
IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

You have this issue because of the `virtual` properties. You try to serialize a class which has a reference to another class, which has a reference to the first, class, which... endless loop.

If you want to serialize an entity, the best thing you can do is use a DTO class, which is a class used only to export your data. In these classes you can't have virtual properties, but what you can do is include the DTO objects of your `ParticipantAddress`.

The other thing you can try, if it isn't a necessity to serialize to XML, is use the Newtonsoft.Json package to serialize the entities. The package has some options to deal with navigational properties.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a region and change ICollection<> to List<> because

> ICollection is an interface and interfaces are not serializable.

But **List<> is a class** and this class implements all the below interfaces:
IList, **ICollection**, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList, IReadOnlyCollection, IEnumerable, IEnumerable.

I kept both Icollection as well as List and put [XmlIgnore] on ICollection.

```
    [XmlRoot("participant", Namespace = "")]
    public partial class Participant
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Participant()
        {
            this.GroupParticipantList = new List<GroupParticipant>();
            this.ParticipantAddressList = new List<ParticipantAddress>();
            this.ParticipantPublisherList = new List<ParticipantPublisher>();
            this.ParticipantJobList = new List<ParticipantJob>();
            this.ParticipantProviderList = new List<ParticipantProvider>();
        }

        [XmlElement("firstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("lastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ParticipantAddress> ParticipantAddress { get; set; }

        #region Custom properties

        [XmlElement("address")]
        public virtual List<ParticipantAddress> ParticipantAddressList { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

But with this option I am having another **Problem**: If I do any single change in my SQL database and if I do update model from database, then I lose manually implemented code like all the XML sentences in this code.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this in the below article to add [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore] to entity.tt template

[Prevent Property from being serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397524/prevent-property-from-being-serialized/58562395#58562395)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using EF, to implement a Web service and couldn't serialize the ICollection<> object.
I hopes this helps you out.

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        sessions = new HashSet<Session>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Session> sessions { get; set; }
}


public class Session
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Datetime start_dtime{ get; set; }
    public Datetime end_dtime{ get; set; }

    public virtual User user{ get; set; }
}
```