# How to prevent a property from being set through model binding in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I've the following `ZapScan` class with a `TargetUrl` property whose purpose is to return the concatenation of the `Url` and `Path` properties.

The `ZapScan` class is also used as a parameter in a controller action, and thus is subject to model binding:

```
[HttpPost, FormatFilter]
    [Consumes("application/json", new string[]{"application/xml"})]
    public ActionResult<ZapScan> OnPost([FromBody] ZapScan scan)
    {
        return HandleRequest(scan);
    }
```

How can I prevent the `TargetUrl` property from being subject to model binding? Is it sufficient that it's a read-only property? What about the general case, where the property is also set-able?

```
public class ZapScan
{
   private string _url;
   private string _path;


   [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
   public string Url
   {
       get
       {
           return _url;
       }
       set
       {
           if (value is null)
           {
               throw new ArgumentNullException();
           }

           _url = value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal) ? value.Remove(value.Length - 1) : value;
       }
   }
   [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
   public string Path
   {
       get
       {
           return _path;
       }
       set
       {
           if (value is null)
           {
               _path = "";
           }
           else
           {
               _path = value.StartsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal) ? value : value.Remove(value.Length - 1);
           }
       }
   }
   public ScanType Type { get; set; } = ScanType.Active;

   public string TargetUrl
   {
       get
       {
           return Url + Path;
       }
   }

   public override string ToString() {
       return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this).ToLower();
   }
}
```

**[Bind] attribute**:
I've been looking at the Bind attribute, but it doesn't appear to have a an `Exclude` property in ASP.NET Core Web API?

```
[Bind(Exclude = "Height, Width")]
```

Comment: [`XmlIgnore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent Property from being serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397524/prevent-property-from-being-serialized)

Comment: I believe there's a [BindNever] attribute you can use on the property.

Comment: If you are using entity-framework you can use [NotMapped] attribute

Comment: @HereticMonkey - doesn’t `XmlIgnore` only apply to serialization and not to data binding?

Comment: @HereticMonkey - isn’t data binding and serialization two different things?

Comment: Why can not have different view model (like ZapScanForPost) without TargetUrl for POST?

Comment: Because it would be redundant to have a second class thats just a copy of the first with one property unbound. There are attributes for this for a reason

Comment: Why did you want to prevent a property from being set through model binding?What the result you wanted?I test your code and could get the value like:`url:"aa",path:"bb",targetUrl:"aabb"`.

Comment: @Rena - because `TargetUrl` is only a convenience property that returns the concatenation of two other properties - it don’t need its own backing field.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a private setter on TargetUrl can help :

```
public string TargetUrl
{
    get
    {
        return Url + Path;
    }

    private set;
}
```

On the other hand, given that you are saying the framework to consume json, maybe just a JsonIgnore will do the trick

```
[JsonIgnore]
public string TargetUrl
{
    get
    {
        return Url + Path;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe no set is similar to readonly not to private. I know readonly is more restrictive than private, but I think this worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

If the property is settable you can use `[BindNever]` on it. Like so:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

public class ZapScan
{
    // ...

    [BindNever]
    public string TargetUrl { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

[Here are the Microsoft docs explaining it.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#bindnever-attribute)

Comment: Doesn't work, it's still bound by FromBody.