# .Net Web Services XML Serializer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, soap, wsdl

I am using VS2015 to consume some old web services (SAP). I can import the WSDL just fine, and all the references come across ok. But, when I try and use the service, it looks like the XML output only includes properties with values. That is not working with the WSDL service. I am using SoapUI to test and it can communicate just fine with the service. Using SoapUI, if I remove some of the outbound XML in the call, it will fail. So, I think my issue is the outbound XML serialization. Any ideas on how to tackle this? Is there a way to mark the properties so they will be output even if they don't have a value? (short of putting a space or something in the field? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design to differentiate between null and empty, have a look at [Suppress Null Value Types from Being Emitted by XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296468/suppress-null-value-types-from-being-emitted-by-xmlserializer)